# How to plot 2 subplots of wav spectogram file?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 2 wav files (with same sampling rate) and I want to display their spectogram side by side.

I'm using the code from here (https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html) to show wav file spectogram:

```
y, sr             = librosa.load(FILE_NO_SPEAKING)
mel_spec_no_speak = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr)

y, sr             = librosa.load(FILE_SPEAKING)
mel_spec_speak    = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr)

D = np.abs(librosa.stft(y))**2
S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(S=D, sr=sr)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)


S_dB          = librosa.power_to_db(S, ref=np.max)
img_no_speak  = librosa.display.specshow(S_dB, 
                                x_axis='time',
                                y_axis='mel', 
                                sr=sr,
                                fmax=8000, 
                                ax=ax1)

img_speak     = librosa.display.specshow(S_dB, 
                                x_axis='time',
                                y_axis='mel', 
                                sr=sr,
                                fmax=8000, 
                                ax=ax2)

#fig.colorbar(?, ax=(ax1, ax2), format='%+2.0f dB')
ax1.set(title='No Speak')
ax2.set(title='Speak')
```

- But I dont know how to set the colorbar with the images of each subplot ?
- In addition I want to enlarge the figure plot size, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the colorbar with the images of each subplot, you can create a single colorbar for the entire figure using `fig.colorbar()` and pass in the `img_no_speak` object as the mappable argument. Find below an example and produced image using waveforms from Librosa:

[image]

```py
import librosa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Load trumpet signal for both cases
y, sr = librosa.load(librosa.ex("trumpet"))
mel_spec_no_speak = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr)
y, sr = librosa.load(librosa.ex("trumpet"))
mel_spec_speak = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr)

# Transform
D = np.abs(librosa.stft(y)) ** 2
S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(S=D, sr=sr)

# Create figure, set up figure size in inches
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))

# Turn to dB, and show
S_dB = librosa.power_to_db(mel_spec_no_speak, ref=np.max)
img_no_speak = librosa.display.specshow(
    S_dB, x_axis="time", y_axis="mel", sr=sr, fmax=8000, ax=ax1
)
ax1.set(title="No Speak")

# Turn to dB, and show
S_dB = librosa.power_to_db(mel_spec_speak, ref=np.max)
img_speak = librosa.display.specshow(
    S_dB, x_axis="time", y_axis="mel", sr=sr, fmax=8000, ax=ax2
)
ax2.set(title="Speak")

# Global colorbar
fig.colorbar(img_no_speak, ax=[ax1, ax2], format="%+2.0f dB")

# Show
plt.show()
```

To enlarge the figure plot size, you can pass in the `figsize` parameter to the `subplots()` function when creating the figure. For example, to create a figure with a width of 12 inches and a height of 6 inches, you can use `figsize=(12, 6)`:

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))
```

Comment: In your solution you ysed only img_no_speak while we have another different img_speak. So your solution show the same image in to sub plots.

Comment: Nope, the images are the same because I have read twice the same data (I don't have access to your data). This solution [is the one provided by matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/colorbar_placement.html); you should use only one for the two mappables within `fig.colorbar()`.